# How to create jndi datasource in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jndi

How to create jndi datasource with the name "jdbc/dblogger" in the springboot application and access inside the custom jar using the code
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/dblogger");

Iam not able to create this bean.This is my existing datasource code 
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
    
 Iam not able to create this bean.This is my existing datasource code .I would like to create another one for jndi datasource with the name "jdbc/dblogger".please help on this.
```

Comment: You don't. You register the datasource in JNDI and do a lookup. But if you are using Spring Boot with an embedded container, why bother with JNDI anyway? Remove the code that uses JNDI and just inject the datasource, that way it doesn't matter where the datasource comes from.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum Thankyou very much for your reply.In my springboot application iam using a thirdparty custom jar which contains the code String dsSource = properties.getProperty("crew.db.source");
     if ("JNDI".equalsIgnoreCase(dsSource)) {
      Context initContext = new InitialContext();
      Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
      ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/dblogger");
     } Here if the datasource is JNDI then we referring the "jdbc/logger".How to create the jndi datasource bean with the name "jdbc/dblogger",please suggest on this.

Comment: You don't create that bean, you register one in JNDI. Nonetheless apparently there is an IF statement in there so there is also another means of creating that class without JNDI.

Comment: @M.Deinum how to register "jdbc/logger" in JNDI in spring boot application,so that we can access later.can u please give any references on this.

Comment: You don't. It doesn't make sense to use JNDI in an embedded container.